# how to get html in autocomplete in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

currently i am doing autocomplete feature using jquery as below

```
 $("#autoCompleteFieldId").autocomplete({minLength:0}, {delay:0}, {source: specValues});
```

here specValues is an array which contains values like "<b>Html text</b>,"normal text" etc...
now i want to display values in autocomplete text box like 
**Html text**
normal text

kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

well your target `#autoCompleteFieldID` should be where the value should be displayed...

I have included the jquery official example below:

You question is not very clear but if you are asking how to get the new value... then you should use the `select` event

> Triggered when an item is selected from the menu; ui.item refers to
>   the selected item. The default action of select is to replace the text
>   field's value with the value of the selected item. Canceling this
>   event prevents the value from being updated, but does not prevent the
>   menu from closing.

**Important**: Should my understanding of your question be incorrect then please do let me know and update your question with a little more information.

**JS Fiddle**: option for you
http://jsfiddle.net/SRdFy/

**Example**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript","AppleScript","Asp","BASIC", "C","C++","Clojure","COBOL","ColdFusion","Erlang","Fortran","Groovy","Haskell","Java","JavaScript","Lisp","Perl","PHP","Python","Ruby","Scala","Scheme"             
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,                        
        });
    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```